# how to reload JSP page after submit form data

Tags: jsp

Just wondering how to refresh the jsp page after submitting data in the form.

```
if (request.getParameter("key") != null){
        if (request.getParameter("value") != null){
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie(request.getParameter("key"), request.getParameter("value"));
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
```

should I add something following the response.addCookie ?

Comment: redirect to same page through sendRedirect() method

Answer (score 0):

suppose you submit to `SubmitServlet` from the form, then redict to the same JSP from it using `RequestDispatcher` or `response.sendRedirect`